# VB.NET ANYCPU ReadProcessMemory

Tags: vb.net, readprocessmemory

So I got this code for 2 years running on x86 , and two weeks ago I tried to compile it to ANY CPU. And it does not work. I did some reading and I did not find anything . I'm a beginner and if you want to help me , I will appreciate it.

```
 <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
    Public BaseAddress As Integer
    Public AllocationBase As Integer
    Public AllocationProtect As Integer
    Public RegionSize As Integer
    Public State As Integer
    Public Protect As Integer
    Public lType As Integer
End Structure
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure SYSTEM_INFO
    Dim dwOemID As Integer
    Dim dwPageSize As Integer
    Dim lpMinimumApplicationAddress As Integer
    Dim lpMaximumApplicationAddress As Integer
    Dim dwActiveProcessorMask As Integer
    Dim dwNumberOrfProcessors As Integer
    Dim dwProcessorType As Integer
    Dim dwAllocationGranularity As Integer
    Dim dwReserved As Integer
End Structure
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint:="VirtualQueryEx", SetLastError:=True), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()>
Public Function VirtualQueryEx(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, ByVal lpAddress As UInteger, ByRef lpBuffer As MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION, ByVal dwLength As Integer) As Integer
End Function
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetSystemInfo", SetLastError:=True), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()>
Public Sub GetSystemInfo(ByRef lpSystemInfo As SYSTEM_INFO)
End Sub
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint:="OpenProcess", SetLastError:=True), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()>
Public Function OpenProcess(ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Integer, ByVal blnheritHandle As Boolean, ByVal dwAppProcessId As Integer) As IntPtr
End Function
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint:="CloseHandle", SetLastError:=True), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()>
Public Function CloseHandle(ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint:="ReadProcessMemory", SetLastError:=True), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()>
Public Function ReadProcessMemory(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByVal lpBuffer() As Byte, ByVal iSize As Integer, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
Public Const PROCESS_VM_READ = (&H10)
Public Const PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = (&H8)
Public Const PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = (&H400)
Public Const PROCESS_READ_WRITE_QUERY = PROCESS_VM_READ + PROCESS_VM_OPERATION + PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION

        Public Sub Test2()
        Dim _targetProcessHandle As IntPtr = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses("solitaire")(0).Handle
        Dim _mbi As MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION, _sysInfo As SYSTEM_INFO
        Dim _mbiSize As Int32 = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(_mbi)
        GetSystemInfo(_sysInfo)
        Dim _addr As Integer = _sysInfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress
        Dim _readBuff(_sysInfo.dwPageSize - 1) As Byte
        Dim _actualBytesRead As Int32 = 0
        Dim _oldPageProtection As UInt32 = 0
        Dim _accessRightsChanged As Boolean = False
        _targetProcessHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_READ_WRITE_QUERY, False, CInt(_targetProcessHandle))
        Dim ret As Integer
        Do
            ret = VirtualQueryEx(_targetProcessHandle, CType(_addr, IntPtr), _mbi, _mbiSize)
            If ret = _mbiSize Then
                If ((_mbi.lType = &H20000) And (_mbi.State = &H1000) And (_mbi.RegionSize > 0)) Then
                    Dim _byteBuff(_mbi.RegionSize) As Byte
                    ReadProcessMemory(_targetProcessHandle, _mbi.BaseAddress, _byteBuff, _mbi.RegionSize, 0)
                    'Do some work
                    Array.Clear(_byteBuff, 0, _byteBuff.Length)
                End If
                _addr = _mbi.BaseAddress + _mbi.RegionSize
            End If
        Loop While _addr < _sysInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress
        CloseHandle(_targetProcessHandle)
    End Sub
```

This works just fine on X86 , but it does not want to run on AnyCpu. Can you help me please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Public Function VirtualQueryEx(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, ByVal lpAddress As IntPtr, ByRef lpBuffer As MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION, ByVal dwLength As IntPtr) As IntPtr`

Comment: did u try just x86 , and x64 ? 32 bit and 64 bit system having some differences while reading bits.

Comment: `Public Function ReadProcessMemory(ByVal hProcess As IntPtr, ByVal lpBaseAddress As IntPtr, ByVal lpBuffer() As Byte, ByVal iSize As IntPtr, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As IntPtr) As Boolean`

Comment: @snoopcommands sir ,I did and it works perfect on X86 and x64 but not on Any CPU. GSerg sir, I modify these 2 functions , works on X64 & X86 but not on Any CPU. Thank you all . I will edit the post, cause on x64 works , my mistake

Comment: in anycpu mode it process bits as same as 32 bit ,thats why you cant get ur process work on 64 bit cpu . I did have  the same issue and made two seperate exe 32 and 64 bit

Answer (score -1):

Are you getting badimageformatexception? I'm assuming you are loading an x86 dll and trying to run it on a x64 machine, any cpu forces your program to run in x64 if cpu is x64. Forcing your program to x86 will still work on x64 machine.

Comment: No sir , i do not get any badimageformatexception erros, It just works fine , but not on ANY CPU.